# Ionic Capcitor build Android unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am receiving an error when attempting to run ionic capacitor build android (details below):

```
PS C:\Users\User\source\repos\imango\src> ionic capacitor build android
```

> npm.cmd i -E @capacitor/android@latest
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: mango@0.0.1
> npm ERR! Found: @capacitor/core@3.7.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/@capacitor/core
> npm ERR!   @capacitor/core@"^3.5.1" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer @capacitor/core@"^4.0.0" from @capacitor/android@4.0.1
> npm ERR! node_modules/@capacitor/android
> npm ERR!   @capacitor/android@"4.0.1" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-06T22_53_19_523Z-debug-0.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

```
    npm.cmd i -E @capacitor/android@latest exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: You should try to remove your node_modules folder and reinstall it 'npm i'. See if it clears things up.

Comment: cap build worked with capacitor 3.0+

Comment: Receiving the same when attempting upgrade capacitor to 4 using the Ionic vscode plugin. tried clearing node_modules and cache and reinstalling with npm install - no help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
ionic capacitor build android
```

Use this:

```
npx cap build android
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your capacitor cli version is still set at 3.6.0 in your
> devDependencies, try changing that to ^4.0.1 and clearing your
> node_modules and removing your package-lock.json and run npm install
> again.

Check this
Copied from her:
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5812

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).